# Android: Back button OnKeyListener inside Fragment is not working

Tags: android

The onKeyListener() in a Fragment is not working now. Here's the part of the code.

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, null);
    ...

    view.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    view.requestFocus();
    view.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {

        // true if the listener has consumed the event, false otherwise.
        // the key event happens twice, when pressing and taking off.
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && !touched) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onKey() method");
                touched = true;
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

try this:

```
 @Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    getView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    getView().requestFocus();
    getView().setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                     //go to previous fragemnt
                    //perform your fragment transaction here
                    //pass data as arguments
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Sorry I just checked out your answer. But in that case, how am I supposed to inflate the `R.layout.fragment` file?

Comment: you can inflate the layout in `oncreateview()`  and listen for key listener in `onViewcreated()`

Comment: Oh gotcha! I was confused because the two names looked almost the same. Anyways I tried it in your way, but it didn't work either.

Comment: when do u want to fire key event? it's not mentioned

Comment: Do you mean when I want to push the back button in the Fragment?

Comment: What I was trying to implement is that I modify some configurations in the fragment, and when I press the back button to go back to the previous Fragment, the changed configuration info appears on the Toast message.

Comment: Let me try to figure it out first.. let me post the solution when I find it. Anyways thanks a lot for your tip!

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me, for both **Fragment** & **DialogFragment**.

For Fragment:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // Disable back press
    requireView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    requireView().requestFocus();
    requireView().setOnKeyListener((v, keyCode, event) -> keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK);
}
```

For DialogFragment:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    requireDialog().setOnKeyListener((dialog, keyCode, event) ->
            // Disable back pressed
            keyCode == android.view.KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK
    );
}
```